# Why does Kivy say Unresolved reference 'Myapp'?

Tags: kivy

```
    import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Myapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="hey")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Myapp().run()
```

Why does Kivy say Unresolved reference 'Myapp' here?

Comment: Might be that the indentation is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Myapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="hey")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Myapp().run()
```

Try this, if statement isn't part of the class so it shouldn't be idented

Answer (score 0):

**This is what helped**

In PyCharmm in the Project Interpreter, add all the packages that start with:

kivy-deps.

With the exclusion of the ones with "dev" in the title

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a ModuleNotFoundError for PIL. Try installing PIL through:

```
pip3 install Pillow
```